# Problematic table migration in laravel

Tags: migration, laravel-5.1

I have a table permission that gives me a lot of problems.

I deleted it from server, and delete his migration file.

In table migration, there is no row with the permission migration.

Just in case, I execute:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

everything fine.

Still, when I execute any of those,

```
composer install
composer update
php artisan migrate
php artisan migrate:rollback
php artisan migrate:refresh
php artisan cache:clear
```

I get:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                              
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table  'nestsp5_laravel.ken_permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from  `ken_permissions`)
```

I searched for references in my migrations with Ctrl+Shift+F that use keyword permissions, but could not find it.

When I create this table manually in db,

```
composer install
composer update
php artisan cache:clear
```

all those work

Even

```
php artisan migrate
```

will create my tables fine ( without permissions that I have deleted )

I could manage it doing tricks, but it will not fix the problem.

Can anybody explain to me what is the problem?

Comment: I find explanation to this problem, but did not solve it, I had to remove all references to model Permission, in models / providers, then refresh my migrations and then, uncomment it again. Any help about doing it better will be appreciated